# Handle click on Link in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

I know the way to handle click on link in UIWebview.
In my current application, I need to handle click on UIWeview then open another UIViewController. However, when I pop back to UIWebView then I can't click that link again.
Please give me some ideas. Thanks

Comment: show your code, what you are writing when you come back to the first view ?

Comment: I don't do anything without pushing and popping view controllers. After the first time click on that link, it becomes disable link